# Returning a Task<TEntity> correctly in ASP

Tags: asp.net, async-await

I have a `GenericRepository` and a `GenericMockRepository`. I'm working with `async` methods.

Here's my code

```
// GenericRepository - uses a DbContext context subclass with connection strings and stuff
public Task<TEntity> GetByIDAsync(object id) {
    return context.FindAsync(id)
}

// GenericMockRepository - uses a List<TEntity> entities
public Task<TEntity> GetByIDAsync(object id) {

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK

    return new Task<TEntity>(() => {
        return entities.SingleOrDefault(entity => {
            var property = entity.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
            if (property != null && property.GetValue(entity) == id) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Basically, the first one is called when the request goes through a browser and the `Controller` is instantiated by the framework. The second one gets called from **Unit Test** project

For both cases, Controller's `Details()` method goes like this:

```
// inside Details()
Customer customer = await UnitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetByIDAsync(id.GetValueOrDefault());
```

And here is the test case:

```
[TestMethod]
    public async void CanRetrieveSingleContact() {
        //Arrange
        SetUp();
        Customer customer = Customers.FirstOrDefault();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = await Controller.Details(customer.ID) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Customer model = result.ViewData.Model as Customer;
        Assert.AreEqual(customer, model);
    }
```

There is no documentation how to async test, so up to this point:

1. if I declare this test method as `void`, it doesn't get tested
2. as Task or Task or Task it runs but never ends nor gives results

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: Also did you start the `Task` once you created it?

Comment: I posted my test case, any ideas? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public async void CanRetrieveSingleContact()
```

To

```
public async Task CanRetrieveSingleContact()
```

TAP programming and unit testing is a bit tricky, and yes, it fails without telling you why.

Test explorer needs to know what it's working on. If you return `void`, it ignores it and goes on its merry way. But if you return `Task`, it knows to wait.

One other thing you are missing is:

```
 public async Task<TEntity> GetByIDAsync(object id)
```

Then

```
return await Task.FromResult<TEntity>(entities.SingleOrDefault( ... ));
```

It needs to wait on your asynchronous method.

Comment: This way, it never ends. Like the task shouldn't take more than 5 seconds, but it never ends. What else is missing?

Comment: Ok, let me add some more.

Comment: OK, so even though the object that calls it uses `await` like this: `await mock.GetByIDAsync(5)`, It's implementation should also go with `await` as you wrote on the last code block?

Comment: Yup, it's one of the pains in TAP programming. If you forget to do it, it silently fails like you saw. When you `await` it gives control back to the original thread.